# WPF, STA thread exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF (MVVM) app.
Using 2 buttons, one to load data from db and another one to delete a selected item.
When clicking the `Load` button, a `LoadCommand` is fired and calls the `StartLoadingThread`

```
private void StartLoadingThread()
{
    ShowLoadProcessing(); // show some text on top of screen ("Loading in progress...")

    ThreadStart ts = delegate
    {
        LoadMyitems();

        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (EventHandler)
        delegate
        {
            HideLoadProcessing(); // hide the text "Loading in progress..."
        }, null, null);
    };
    ts.BeginInvoke(ts.EndInvoke, null);
}
```

Works fine, now when I select an item and click the `Delete` button, the `DeleteItemCommand` is fired and calls the `StartDeletingThread`

```
private void StartDeletingThread()
{
    ShowDeleteProcessing(); // Show on top of screen "Deleting in progress..."

    ThreadStart ts = delegate
    {
        DeleteSelectedItem();

        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (EventHandler)
        delegate
        {
            HideDeletingProcessing();
        }, null, null);
    };
    ts.BeginInvoke(ts.EndInvoke, null);
}
```

When `StartDeletingThread` is started, I'm getting the following exception:

```
{"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."}
```

Comment: @chrfin Which Main do you mean? It's a wpf app, I've checked in obj/debug/App.g.cs and there is an attr [System.STAThreadAttribute()]

Comment: Check out this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e4c9b1d-9181-49f8-96b7-65e325ef4a47/sta-thread-application-using-automatically-generated-main-function?forum=wpf

Comment: @chrfin Like I said, a [System.STAThreadAttribute()] is already there, the link you suggested is not helping :(

Comment: From which thread are you calling the StartDeletingThread method. Can you try Invoking that method safely from your Application.Current.Dispatcher ?

Comment: @MarkoDevcic I've tried to do it like this: System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(StartLoadingThread)); but still getting the same exception

Comment: Wow, you need to brush up on threading.  Your code is a bit mind boggling... calling BeginInvoke on a ThreadStart is about as weird as I've ever seen.  Also, if you've got an exception, always call ToString() on it to get the full details and add that to your question.  You haven't said *where* in StartDeletingThread it occurs.  Lastly, all this STAThreadAttribute bullshit is just that.  Has no place in a WPF app.  It only works on the entry point of an application, not on any old random method.  You don't need random stuff here, just do your UI work on the UI thread.

Comment: DeleteSelectedItem is called on a thread pool thread, and (can't tell, you didn't show us, and without the call stack...) may touch the UI.  I'd wager the problem is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, though I am a bit newbie in WPF, you will have to replace `this.BeginInvoke` with something what is doing same in WPF (Dispatcher). Also code may not compile (add `Action` type conversion for Thread?), but idea is to simply start thread (you invoke it, for some reasons, why?) and in that thread invoke UI operation after deleting.

```
private void StartDeletingThread()
{
    ShowDeleteProcessing(); // Show on top of screen "Deleting in progress..."
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        DeleteSelectedItem();
        this.BeginInvoke(() => HideDeletingProcessing());
    }.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking StartDeletingThread using the application dispatcher like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,new       
Action(()=>StartDeletingThread())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void StartDeletingThread()
{
    ShowDeleteProcessing(); // Show on top of screen "Deleting in progress..."
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DeleteSelectedItem();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)HideDeletingProcessing);
    });
}
```

probably will blow up at `DeleteSelectedItem();`.  I know we all love to show progress bars for actions that take less than a second, but why bother when it leads to questions on StackOverflow?

```
private void StartDeletingThread()
{
    DeleteSelectedItem();
}
```

Done and done.  I seriously doubt it takes a long time to delete the selected item.

If, in some rare case it does...  then you need to find out in `DeleteSelectedItem` where the UI is getting touched, and use the application's dispatcher to do the touching.

(Side note, here's how you'd safely multithread in 4.5, using async/await... safe, as long as you understand the repercussions of `async void`, that is)

```
private async void StartDeletingThread()
{
    // we're in the UI thread
    ShowDeleteProcessing();
    await DeleteSelectedItem();
    // back in the UI thread
    HideDeletingProcessing();
}

private Task DeleteSelectedItem()
{
    // doing the work on a Task thread
    return Task.Run(() => DeleteSelectedItem = null);
}
```